# Different paths for ruby in geany's terminal and user's gnome terminal

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, path, gnome-terminal, geany

I'm trying to use geany like ide for ruby. But i cannot configure it for uses the correct ruby version. Here is the answers from user's terminal:

```
yaroslav@yaroslavpc:~$ ruby -v
  ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]
yaroslav@yaroslavpc:~$ which ruby
  /home/yaroslav/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
yaroslav@yaroslavpc:~$ which rake
  /home/yaroslav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/rake
```

And here is the answers in geany terminal (in preferences set 'gnome-terminal'):

```
yaroslav@yaroslavpc:~$ ruby -v
  ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]
yaroslav@yaroslavpc:~$ which ruby
  /usr/bin/ruby
yaroslav@yaroslavpc:~$ which rake
  /home/yaroslav/.rvm/bin/rake
```

I have a suspicion that the case in the terminal profile. But, even so, I do not know how to solve this problem. A little help would be very cool.

**Edit:**

for user's shell `ps -p $$`:

```
yaroslav@yaroslavpc:~$ ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3021 pts/1    00:00:01 bash
```

for geany's shell `ps -p $$`:

```
yaroslav@yaroslavpc:~$ ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 8874 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
```

file `~/.profile`:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

file `~/.bashrc`:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

file `~/.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

**Edit 2**
Thanks a lot @Felix

I change shell comand in geany to `/bin/bash --login`. After that in geany's shell I execute some command:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default --install
gem install rails
gem install rake
```

After that:

```
yaroslav@yaroslavpc:~$ ruby -v
  ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]
yaroslav@yaroslavpc:~$ which ruby
  /home/yaroslav/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
yaroslav@yaroslavpc:~$ which rake
  /home/yaroslav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rake
yaroslav@yaroslavpc:~$ which rails
  /home/yaroslav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the "geany-terminal" does not act as a login shell or is otherwise a different shell, as it does not load your rvm start-up script.

First, find out which shell(s?) you are running with `ps -p $$`, then figure out how to get your rvm kickin' ([rvm.io](http://rvm.io)). You will likely end in looking at your ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile and ~/.bash_profile .

Comment: thanks a lot.
In ~\.bashrc i found just one string about rvm:
`PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`.
And `ps -p $$` give me different TTY.

I have one additional question. I read [on rvm.io](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal) about checking "Run command as a login shell" in gnome-terminal for rvm. But i can't do that in geany.

Comment: I guess you can create a profile like hinted at at rvm.io and then configure geany to make gnome-terminal use that profile (https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/3.7/gnome-terminal.html) . I am only guessing though.